Azure Service Bus Queue : Facing Socket Exception on running load testing
We are running the load testing on one of the functions and getting socket exception.
Total messages - Sedning around 10,000 messages(Each is less than 80KB in Size) 
Memory size is set to - 10 GB and Auto scale set to 20 GB 
Max message size is set to - 1 MB and Auto scale set to 5MB 
Partition is Disabled


Any Help is appreciated. 

Full Error Message: One or more errors occurred. (Exception Publishing Message via AMQP .NET Lite.) Exception Publishing Message via AMQP .NET Lite. An operation on a socket could not be performed because the system lacked sufficient buffer space or because a queue was full.

Those are not the dependencies used by the Azure SDK extensions packages.   Can you share the code for what you're working with?
